# Prettier same line bracket for self-closing tags

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsx, prettier

Is there any way to make prettier put the bracket of a self closing tag on the same line as the last attribute of a JSX element?

Here is what I mean:

[image]

I wanted to put it on the same line as the last attribute to save some space.
Also, I already have configured prettier with `bracketSameLine` but this only applies to non self-closing elements.

Comment: No, you can't. Prettier has very few configuration options by design. It offers a small amount of control, but in the end it it designed to take the decision on how to style certain code elements off the developers, as it is stated in the [documentation](https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html): _"By far the biggest reason for adopting Prettier is to stop all the ongoing debates over styles."_. If you want a customizable formatter, Prettier is the wrong tool to use.

Answer (score 0):

This config work for me, give it a try:

```json
{
    "bracketSameLine": true
}
```